# Variables for all views in Sinatra erb files

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

What is the best way to assign variables in sinatra that can be used on all views(all erb files).

I know it can be done using global variables in the main file lets say app.rb but is there a better way to do it without using global variables?
eg in app.rb, i can do:

```
@@a = "hello"
get '/' do
    erb :index
end

get '/hi' do
    erb :page
end
```

and in index.erb and page.erb files:

```
<%= @@a %>
```

But is there a way to do so without using global variables or is global variables the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Whats wrong in using just `@a`?  That should work

Comment: You can use a constant. You can define a helper method. You can use session variables for per-user values. You can use a global variable. Perhaps if you clarified your actual needs, you would get answers that help you more specifically.

Comment: hey guys, i found that using `helper do; end;` is the best way to go about doing it. thanks everyone for your answers. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Create a module with constants of all the strings/variables you want accessible. All views will have access to your modules:

```
module StringConstants
    LOGIN_PAGE = "Welcome to X"
    LOGOUT = "See you again soon"
end
```

then in your views:

```
<%= StringConstants::LOGIN_PAGE %>
```

Comment: Thanks @martin. and what is the best way to define define variables that will be used across all routes in the main app.rb file? Where and how should i define it? for eg, where should i define a variable that i would like to use in both `'/'` and `'/hi'` in my example?

Comment: Is this a constant, or something that will vary from user to user after logging in?

Comment: i wanted to define a variable that could be used in all routes within app.rb as well as in all the erb files. i just didn't want to use a global variable.

Comment: That's not a global variable. You still have to go to mention the module to get to its inner var.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are usually used for cross view access. In sinatra, it's just your standard hash:

```
session[:whatever] = "Hello"
```

And that can be accessed anywhere once set. It will persist independently per user session.

For example, a common helper I use is:

```
# set session[:user] = user's ID when they log in

def user
  @user ||= User.get(session[:user])
end
```

You'd access that in your views or controllers using `user`.